# How would I put the values of transformY between frames 1-120 into an array for an expression?

Tags: arrays, animation, 3d, expression, maya

I have pCube1 with transformY animated from frames 1-120. I created an attribute, lowTy and highTy, that I'd like to show the lowest and highest value of transformY's animation.

Here is what I have so far:

Lowest value:

```
float $array = {THE MISSING PIECE};
$sortedarray = sort($array);
lowTy = $sortedarray[0]
```

Highest value:

```
float $array = {THE MISSING PIECE};
int $arraysize = size($array);
$sortedarray = sort($array);
highTy = $sortedarray[$arraysize-1]
```

The missing piece is being able to put the values of transformY from frames 1-120 into an array. As a note, I don't just need the keyframe values, but the values from all 120 frames keyframed or not. The lowest value of pCube1.transformY is from the tangent handles.

Additional question: How would I return the position of a given value within an array?

Example:

```
$array = {55, 23, 45, 9, 3, 12, 23)
```

How do I return the position of 9? (which should be 3)
And in the case I try to return the position of 23, how would I choose first (position 1) or second (position 6)?

In the context of my pCube1 scenario, I'd like to quickly locate what frame the highest and lowest values are on.

EDIT: Added a photo for more clarification.

[Graph editor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htHWT.png)

If I were to modify translateY the lines indicating lowTy and highTy should follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES! I found a way to formulate an expression to do this using loops and getAttr to populate an array with all the values of the attribute in chronological order then used sort to find the lowest value:

```
float $arr[];
int $i;
float $data = 0;
int $maxLoop = `playbackOptions -query -aet`;
for($i=1;$i<$maxLoop;$i++)
    {
        $data = `getAttr -t $i pCube1.translateY`;
        $arr[$i] = $data;
    }
$arrsort = sort($arr);
pCube1.test7 = $arrsort[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getAttr command to query the attribute at a specific time:

```
float $array[200];
for(int $i=0; $i<200; $i++)
{
   $array[$i] = `getAttr "pCube1.ty" -t $i`;
}
```

For these types of work I recommend the usage of python where you can do:

```
import pymel.core as pm

node = pm.PyNode("pCube1")
v = []
for i in range(200):
  v.append(node.ty.get(t=i))
v.sort()
minValue = v[0]
maxValue = v[-1]
```

For your additional question you can try the `floatArrayFind()` or `intArrayFind()` commands.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, I'm analyzing the responses I've gotten from both reddit and stackoverflow and seeing how they all can fit within what I need.

I'll make a proper reply once I've tried your code out.

As a little explanation on why I would even need to locate low or high values... I have a few unconventional purposes for Maya. I use it within our CAD environment for creating motion profiles, basic motion analysis, as well as converting mesh to solids. Being able to locate and display low and high values within the graph editor would help me with the first two.

Comment: For some reason I couldn't quite get $array[$i] = `getAttr "pCube1.ty" -t $i` to work, so I made a workaround with another variable. Was finally able to put together an expression to do that I needed. Thanks for the help!

Just curious, is there a benefit to do python over just doing it as an expression? (I have to learn python... which is why I opted to figure out an expression method to do this.)